# How can I ignore extra tuple items when deserializing with Serde? ("trailing characters" error)

Tags: rust, serde

Serde ignores unknown named fields when deserializing into regular structs. How can I similarly ignore extra items when deserializing into tuple structs (e.g. from a heterogeneous JSON array)?

For example, this code ignores the extra `"c"` field just fine:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct { a: String, b: i32 }

fn test_deserialize() -> MyStruct {
    ::serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>(r#"
    {
        "a": "foo",
        "b": 123,
        "c": "ignore me"
    }
    "#).unwrap()
}
// => MyStruct { a: "foo", b: 123 }
```

By contrast, this fails on the extra item in the tuple:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyTuple(String, i32);

fn test_deserialize_tuple() -> MyTuple {
    ::serde_json::from_str::<MyTuple>(r#"
        [
            "foo",
            123,
            "ignore me"
        ]
    "#).unwrap()
}
// => Error("trailing characters", line: 5, column: 13)
```

I'd like to allow extra items for forward compatibility in my data format. What's the easiest way to get Serde to ignore extra tuple items when deserializing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can implement a custom `Visitor` which ignores rest of the sequence. Be aware that the whole sequence must be consumed. This is an important part (try to remove it and you'll get same error):

```rust
// This is very important!
while let Some(IgnoredAny) = seq.next_element()? {
    // Ignore rest
}
```

Here's a working example:

```rust
use std::fmt;

use serde::de::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer, IgnoredAny, SeqAccess, Visitor};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyTuple(String, i32);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyTuple {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct MyTupleVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MyTupleVisitor {
            type Value = MyTuple;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("struct MyTuple")
            }

            fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut seq: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error>
            where
                V: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let s = seq
                    .next_element()?
                    .ok_or_else(|| de::Error::invalid_length(0, &self))?;
                let n = seq
                    .next_element()?
                    .ok_or_else(|| de::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?;

                // This is very important!
                while let Some(IgnoredAny) = seq.next_element()? {
                    // Ignore rest
                }

                Ok(MyTuple(s, n))
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_seq(MyTupleVisitor)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let two_elements = r#"["foo", 123]"#;
    let three_elements = r#"["foo", 123, "bar"]"#;

    let tuple: MyTuple = serde_json::from_str(two_elements).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(tuple.0, "foo");
    assert_eq!(tuple.1, 123);

    let tuple: MyTuple = serde_json::from_str(three_elements).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(tuple.0, "foo");
    assert_eq!(tuple.1, 123);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For JSON, I'd combine [`RawValue`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.29/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html) and a custom deserialization:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyTuple(String, i32);

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyTupleFutureCompat<'a>(
    String,
    i32,
    #[serde(default, borrow)] Option<&'a serde_json::value::RawValue>,
);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyTuple {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let t: MyTupleFutureCompat = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Ok(MyTuple(t.0, t.1))
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let json = r#"[
        "foo",
        123,
        "ignore me"
    ]"#;
    let d: MyTuple = serde_json::from_str(json)?;
    println!("{:?}", d);
    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423)
- [Is there a way to deserialize arbitrary JSON using Serde without creating fine-grained objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49079533/155423)
- [Why can Serde not derive Deserialize for a struct containing only a &Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56394620/155423)